# Uber api Error occurred during authentication: mismatching_redirect_uri

Tags: android, uber-api

sessionConfiguration = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
                .setClientId(ClientID)
                .setServerToken(ServerToken)
                .setRedirectUri("https://www.policyplan.in/UberCab/uber_redirectUri.php?code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE")
                .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX)
                .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS))
                .build();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to post clear and well-formed questions - in this case, looks like you have a problem with redirect URL. If you read Uber [documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/android) - redirect URL needs to match URL you have specified at your application dashboard. So remove **?code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE** and use redirect URL as per your application setup.

Comment: Thank you vary much

Comment: If the answer was helpful can you please complete it